# Issue with an installed public Github package: how and where can I raise my point?

Tags: macos, development, software, developer-program, git

Recently, I habe some issues with a (public) software package available on `Github` which I would like to communicate to the developer such that others can follow the discussion.

How and where is the right procedure / place to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

[Create an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/creating-an-issue):

> Issues can be used to keep track of bugs, enhancements, or other requests. For more information, see "[About issues.](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-issues)"